# my javascript function cant running all code

Tags: javascript, css

please help me to solve it, if write like it :

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("name-page").style.width = "738px";
    document.getElementById("news").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.getElementById("ida").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.getElementById("name-page").style.width = "930px";
    document.getElementById("news").style.marginLeft = "125px";
    document.getElementById("ida").style.marginLeft = "125px";
}
```

style `id=news` can changes, but style `id=ida` cant changes
if write like it :

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("name-page").style.width = "738px";
    document.getElementById("ida").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.getElementById("news").style.marginLeft = "0";
}


function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.getElementById("name-page").style.width = "930px";
    document.getElementById("ida").style.marginLeft = "125px";
    document.getElementById("news").style.marginLeft = "125px";
}
```

style `id=news` cant changes, but style `id=ida` changes

please help me, sorry for my language

Comment: Can you show corresponding html?

Comment: I won't click on those links, but it seems obvious that you use the same javascript file for two html pages. You should consider using variables (`var idaElem = document.getElementById("ida");`) and check whether it is null/undefined, before trying to access `.style.margin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check existing of element before set property:

```
...
if(document.getElementById("news")) {
    document.getElementById("news").style.marginLeft = "0";
}    
if(document.getElementById("ida")) {
    document.getElementById("ida").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
...
```